# How to make shorten mac terminal prompt in bold using powerlevel10k?

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, prompt

I'm using `oh-my-zsh`, `powerlevel10k`, `colorls` and `fig` to customize my mac terminal. Now i have just one issue that i want the `current directory` name in **bold.**

And one more problem that i want to change the color of  which is placed at the starting of the each prompt. How to achieve it ??

See the image below to better understand:
[image]